# "Serenity" vs. "sereneness"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Are these interchangeable, or is there a semantic difference between them? When should I use *serenity* vs. *sereneness?*

Comment: Not very different from the *-ness* and *-ity* suffixes of any other word. There *is* a difference. I'd say the question is GR.

Comment: @Kris - It may be better suited to ELL but I wouldn't say General Reference.  Simply looking these two up in a dictionary you wouldn't see a difference and as you said - there is a clear answer for which one you should use.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be any academic difference judging from their dictionary [definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serenity) and I am not aware of any subtle difference between the two:

> Sereneness - noun form of serene
>
> Serenity - noun, having the state or quality of being serene

In practice, however, the usage of *sereneness* is practically nil compared to serenity, as evidenced by this [NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sereneness,serenity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Adding '-ness' usually turns an adjective into a noun. But there are other ways depending on the adjective. In other words, 'sereneness' is not really a word because 'serenity' already is there. (or those who have (erroneously) used the word 'sereneness' couldn't remember...the other one). Just because the dictionary has an entry for it doesn't mean anybody actually uses it.

Comment: @Mitch - The fact that M-W calls it out explicitly makes it a "real word" in my book, but I think we are in agreement that serenity is more appropriate.